# Principal Component Regression with a Generalized Linear MIXED EFFECTS Model

Tags: mixed-model, generalized-linear-model, pca, regression-coefficients

According to the wiki page on [Principal Component Regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_regression#:%7E:text=In%20statistics%2C%20principal%20component%20regression,a%20standard%20linear%20regression%20model.), it is possible to transform the beta values obtained from doing regression with PCA data into beta values for the original features. This is because, if $X$ is your original data and $Z=\textbf{X}V_k$ is the transformation of that data using $k$ principal components, your model can either be
$$\textbf{Y}=\textbf{X}\beta_X \textrm{ or } \textbf{Y}=\textbf{Z}\beta_Z$$ where $\beta_X$ and $\beta_Z$ are respectively the coefficients you get when doing regression on the original and transformed data. From this, it follows that
$$\textbf{X}\beta_X=\textbf{Z}\beta_Z\\ \textbf{X}\beta_X=\textbf{X}V_k\beta_Z\\ \beta_X=V_k\beta_Z$$
I would like to apply this same logic to a generalized linear mixed effects model $g(E[y|u])=\textbf{X}\beta_X + W_Xu$ where $W_X$ is the random effects design matrix and $u$ are the coefficients for the random effects. I get to:
$$\textbf{X}\beta_X + W_Xu = \textbf{Z}\beta_Z + W_Zu\\ \textbf{X}\beta_X + W_Xu = \textbf{X}V_k\beta_Z + W_Zu$$ with the left side showing the model for the original data and the right side showing the model for the transformed data.
I am not entirely sure if I can ignore the random effects terms and relate the beta coefficients between the two scenarios.

My original intuition was that there is a theoretical assumption that the two models are identical/near identical, hence the fact that we can set them equal to each other when thinking about simple Principal Component Regression. That is, we assume that since $Y$ is the same regardless of which model we choose, the fixed effects components in the non-mixed models are equivalent/converged to equivalent quantities. This in mind, is it valid to believe that in the case of the mixed models, we are making the theoretical assumption that the fixed effects components and random effects components are identical regardless of the transformation of the data? That is, that each component contains the same information regardless of if that info was obtained via the original data or transformed data?